# How exactly do usenet/nntp/newsgroups work?

Tags: usenet, newsgroups, nntp

I recently found a new way to share files, and I am curious about how exactly this may work.

For example, I gained access to my ISP's nntp server. Is anything I see on my ISP's server stored on their servers and owned by them, or are they mixing in content from other providers? How can I find out?

Comment: where does you sharing files come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you see is stored on their server, but certainly isn't owned by them.  Usenet messages are shared using a peer-to-peer protocol, as Wikipedia [explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet#Technical_details):

> Usenet is a set of protocols for generating, storing and retrieving news "articles" (which resemble Internet mail messages) and for exchanging them among a readership which is potentially widely distributed. These protocols most commonly use a flooding algorithm which propagates copies throughout a network of participating servers. Whenever a message reaches a server, that server forwards the message to all its network neighbors that haven't yet seen the article. Only one copy of a message is stored per server, and each server makes it available on demand to the (typically local) readers able to access that server. The collection of Usenet servers has thus a certain peer-to-peer character in that they share resources by exchanging them, the granularity of exchange however is on a different scale than a modern peer-to-peer system and this characteristic excludes the actual users of the system who connect to the news servers with a typical client-server application, much like an email reader.

You can find the origin of messages using the `Path` header, which shows the origin server and the servers it passed through before it made it to your ISP's server.  RFC 1036 [explains this mechanism in detail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1036#section-2.1.6).

Some newsreaders allow you to *view all headers*, while others allow you to *view message source*.  Either way will reveal this information.  However, keep in mind that Usenet headers can be falsified, just like e-mail headers.